# How to set different Security settings depending on the user in ASP.NET VB MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, security, penetration-testing

I am trying to create a ASP.net visual basic site for pen-testing training (think web goat, DVWA and hacme bank) in visual studio 2013.

I want to program this myself and not use the ones already available as this will help me learn a lot more in both programming and pen-testing.

I have made the site as secure as I can and I am trying to create different security levels depending on the user that is logged in. i.e. for user 'low' the security should be very little while for 'high' it should be as strong as I can make it.

Is there anyway of doing this or is there any better way to go about it?

For example is there a way to use different web.config/global configs for different users and not just change these when setting up the site (i.e. not just deploying the site with different web.config each time, web.debug.config, web.release.config etc.)

Comment: Before that, you really need to understand ASP.NET's security (defence against hacks), authentication (who is the user) and authorization (what is permitted) models (they are different). Configuration is a different thing - why should user settings be held in a site's configuration instead of the user's profile? You can start with the [Security](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) secion of the MVC site itself

Comment: I'm not looking for the user settings to be changed but the configuration for the site to be changed depending on the user that is logged in. It doesn't have to be a direct correlation and any work around to achieve the same effect would be sufficient. The web.config file contains a lot of security settings that I would like to be different depending on the user. As these settings cover the site as a whole, using different configuration files will help with creating the vulnerabilities. If using different configurations will not work then I'm looking for another way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: *Which* setting do you want to vary per user and why? You are confusing *authorisation* with configuration. Configuration isn't user-specific, it affects the entire site. Role and permission assignments aren't part of configuration. If you want a user to be able to read one page but not another, you assign or revoke the equivalent permissions. First though you'd have to define what these are.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, the configuration is not user specific so I was looking for a way to have the user get some sort of tag that would load/use a different config file. Changing what the user views makes little difference to something like uglify for the obfuscation of data or having the low user settings be true for createPersistentCookie instead of false like it is at the strong security settings. I'm not looking to change the authorization, role, permission assignments or anything of the like.